# Calculate the sum of obervation values with conditions

Tags: r

The given data is like this:

```
df<-data.frame(farmer=c("F1","F1","F1","F2","F2","F2","F3","F4","F4"),
               c2=c(4,4,5,3,3,3,1,2,1))
df
```

[image: img of the data]
Question is: I would like to get the sum of farmer whose values in the c2 column are the same.

The output of this problem is 2. But how to use code to realize it? Which function should be used?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below

```
nrow(unique(subset(df,ave(c2,farmer)==c2)))
```

where `subset`+ `ave` filters out the farmers who have identical `c2` values, and `nrow` + `unique` helps count the number of those farmers.